# Autohide not working well with 3 panels

Tags: ubuntu-mate, autohide

I have 3 panels.

When I set each of them to autohide, only one panel shows when I hover the mouse over it.

Is there a way to have it show all 3 panels?

Ubuntu-Mate 18.04

[image]
[image]

Comment: Screenshot of hidden and shown panels would be useful.

Comment: @N0rbert Done. I could not get the 3rd panel to show.